# How do I include JSTL variables from another file?

Tags: jstl

I would like to have a JSTL file of "constants" and reference them in other files.

e.g.

constants.jsp:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:set var="colour" value="blue"/>
<c:set var="car">Audi</c:set>
```

---

Other file:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>

<c:import url="constants.jsp"/>
<p>I drive an ${car} which is ${colour}</p>
```

---

The code above (obviously) does not work.  How can I get something similar to work?

Bonus points if I can use namespaces as well.

Answer (score 5):

You could use an include directive:

```
<%@include file="/constants.jsp" %>
```

Or you could use a dynamic include, but then the variables would have to be stored in the request, rather than the page scope:

```
<jsp:include page="/constants.jsp" />

<c:set var="colour" value="blue" scope="request"/>
<c:set var="car" scope="request">Audi</c:set>
```

But the best way would probably be to put all these constants in an object, and store this object in the request (or session, or application) from a servlet or filter:

```
private class Constants {

    private String color = "blue";
    private String car = "Audi";

    public String getColor() {
        return color;
    }

    public String getCar() {
        return car;
    }
}

...

request.setAttribute("constants", new Constants());

...

<p>I drive an ${constants.car} which is ${constants.color}</p>
```